# jQuery selector, starts with and regex

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have following markup:

```
<div id="contract_data">
    <input type="text" id="" class="required rel_name" />   
    <input type="text" id="" class="required rel_phone" />  
    <input type="text" id="" class="required rel_address" />    

</div>
<div id="invoice_data">
    <input type="text" id="" class="required rel_name" />   
    <input type="text" id="" class="required rel_phone" />
    <input type="text" id="" class="required rel_address" />
</div>
```

I need to  programatically copy data from first div to 2nd one. I need to detect field purpose (name, phone etc, and copy data only to a proper field). Previously I wanted to use "rel" attribute, but Iam not able to this anymore, so I've decided to use css class.

Could you help me with builing jquery selector?
I need to loop first div with jquery's each function, and in each loop iteration choose input element from 2nd div with the same rel_class_name attribute.

Edit:

My previous solution, which worked (before I was forced to abandon "rel" attribute on inputs):

```
var inputRelElms = thisstep.find("input[rel]"); // selects input with rel attr, in first div 
inputElms.each(function(){ 
var rel = $(this).attr('rel'), val = $(this).val();
var targetElm = relElm.find("input[rel="+rel+"]"); //selects input with same rel in 2nd div
if(targetElm.val() == ''){
    targetElm.val(val);
}
}
```

Comment: I've forgot to mention: each input may (or not) gave additional classes.

Comment: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21529723/edit) your post if you need to add more info.

Comment: Post your javascript/jQuery attempt, if any...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#contract_data input').each(function (index) {
    $('#invoice_data input:eq(' + index + ')').val(this.value);
});
```

---

Updated After OP's comment

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/n34bB/)

```
$('#contract_data input').each(function (index) {
    var cls = $(this).prop('class').match(/rel_.*\s?/g);
    $('#invoice_data input.' + cls).val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Indexes may be different in each DIV. My original code was only an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('button').click(function () {
    //iterate through each input in contract
    $('#contract_data input').each(function () {
        //using a regex find the rel_* class name
        var clazz = this.className.match(/\b(rel_.*?)\b/)[1];
        //copy the value to the input element in invoice with the same class
        $('#invoice_data .' + clazz).val(this.value)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zNWDm/)

Answer (score 0):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BXBJq/6/)***

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $('#invoice_data input').each(function () {
        var targetclass = '.' + this.className.split(" ").join('.');
        var targetvalue = $('#contract_data ' + targetclass).val();
        $('#invoice_data '+ targetclass).val(targetvalue);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each input boxes in first div collection, find corresponding class input box in another div and assigned appropriate values.

Please find below code for the same:

```
$('#contract_data input').each(function(){
    var rel_class = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[1];
    var inv_inputBox = $('#invoice_data').find('input.'+rel_class);
    if(typeof inv_inputBox !== "undefined" && inv_inputBox !== null){
      $(inv_inputBox).val($(this).val());
    }
 });
```